# Flex app: framerate property is NaN

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have an AS3 App class e.g (pseudo code)

```
public class MyApp extends Application
{
        protected function onRender():void
        {
            trace("frameRate = "+frameRate);
        }
}
```

and this is then extended by the app MXML:

```
<MyApp width="100%" height="100%" frameRate="30" enterFrame="onRender()">
...
</MyApp>
```

The app appears to be running at the right speed, but in MyApp.onRender(), frameRate is seen as NaN (in the debugger too if I step through).
Why is this? How *should* I be obtaining the application's FPS property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Language Reference has this note for `frameRate` in the Application class:

> **Note**: This property cannot be set by ActionScript code; it must be set in MXML code.

If you use `stage.frameRate` in your trace it should give you the framerate you assigned to the Application.  You might need to throw a `try-catch` statement around the `trace`, since the `enterFrame` event can be dispatched before `stage` is instantiated.

Comment: yes `Stage.frameRate` works. But I'm not trying to _set_ it in the AS3 code, only read it... so why does the getter return NaN?

Comment: I don't know for sure.  The generated source shows that a frameRate assignment in the Application becomes a statement [SWF(frameRate=value)] in the AS.  My guess would be that since values in metadata statements aren't bindable, frameRate isn't a true property (with a getter and setter), but only a shorthand for the [SWF()] statement.  Hence it has no meaning in AS3 code, either for setting or getting.  But, again, I'm just guessing.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem. You might be interested to know that Flash Builder 4 also refuses to highlight (and show the help tooltip) for the frameRate attribute.